# Directed Graphs on at most 9 vertices with some properties

Tags: graph-theory, gap, sagemath

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of [strongly connected digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) with $\leq 9$ vertices, up to isomorphism.

Asuume that a directed edge from vertex $v$ to $w$, if exists, is unique; and in this case, there is no directed edge from $w$ to $v$.

Is this family easy to enumerate, say using GAP or SAGE?

---

**Note:** The elements of $\mathcal{F}$ have following properties:

(1) Each graph $G$ in $\mathcal{F}$ is connected and has $\leq 9$ vertices.

(2) For any distinct vertices $v,w$ of $G$, there is a directed path from $v$ to $w$.

(3) [**Edit**-from Smylic's comment]Every vertex has *at least* one incoming  and one outgoing edge.

(4) If there is directed edge from $v$ to $w$, then no directed edge from $w$ to $v$.

Is it easy to obtain enumeration of the family $\mathcal{F}$, say using some softwares such as GAP, SAGE etc.?

I have handeled GAP for groups, but no idea whether we can handle directed graphs there.

Any suggestions for this problems? Also I would appreciate for suggestions of references on such graphs, their properties.

Comment: Can you give some details on which types of properties you might be interested in?  Right now, your question is very broad ...

Comment: I edited and wrote as precise as possible the question; hope that it is clear.

Comment: Did you mean in (3) that vertex has **at least** one incoming edge and **at least** one outgoing edge? (Otherwise you are considering only directed cycles.)

Comment: yes, you are right. I edited it. Thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

It took less that second to compute those up to 5 vertices, less than minute for up to 6 vertices. I guess you could run this up to 8 vertices in a week, but ninth vertex needs something more clever.

```
N = 5
def f(g):
    v = g.order()-1
    if v < 1: return True
    for v_ in g.neighbor_out_iterator(v):
        if g.has_edge(v_, v):
            return False
    return True
sum(1 for g in digraphs(N, augment='vertices', property=f) if g.is_strongly_connected())
```